# How to remove/insert a div element with JavaScript in responsive design?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm constructing a responsive design website and I'm having a problem as to how to rearrange the position of the navigation from desktop to mobile and back, so it's consistent. In the JavaScript function, I have a listener called `window.addEventListener("resize", rearrangeNav);`, but it keeps triggering the event listener every time I resize the window and continually adding and removing the nav. I, only want rearrange to run once there was a change between desktop and mobile responsive design. In other words, pseudo code-wise, `insert navPrimary into colRight if width >= 768px else remove navPrimary if width <= 767px`. Is there another solution instead of using the resizing function that keeps executing the script? If there is a simpler way to insert and remove based on window size, I'm all for it!

**HTML:**

```
<a id="logo" href="index.html" title="Return to Home Page">HELLO WORLD</a>

<!-- menu bar for mobile nav --> 
<div id="nav-btn" onclick="toggleNav();"> </div>
<div id="navPrimary">
    <ul><li><a href="index1.html">under-construction</a></li><li><a href="index2.html">houses</a></li><li><a href="index3.html">cabins</a></li><li><a href="index4.html">renovations</a></li><li><a href="index5.html">competitions</a></li><li><a href="index6.html">lil'</a></li><li><a href="index7.html">media</a></li><li><a href="index8.html">studio</a></li><li><a href="index9.html">contact</a></li></ul>
</div>

<table id="contentRow" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td id="colLeft" width="800" valign="top"><img src="images/home.jpg" /></td>
    <td id="colRight" valign="top" style="display:none;">
<!-- insert navPrimary if width >= 768px else remove navPrimary if width <= 767px -->
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("resize", rearrangeNav); // call the event listener based on the resized window
    function rearrangeNav()
    {
        var nav = document.getElementById("navPrimary"); // retrieve the navigation id
        var colLeft = document.getElementById("colLeft");
        var colRight = document.getElementById("colRight");

        if(document.body.clientWidth <= 768) // MOBILE
        {
            colRight.style.display = "none"; // hide the desktop nav
            nav.parentNode.removeChild(nav); // remove the div

        }
        else if(document.body.clientWidth > 768) // DESKTOP
        {
            colRight.style.display = "block"; // display the desktop nav
            // insert the nav in colRight column
            colRight.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<div id="navPrimary"><ul><li><a href="index3976.html?area=under-construction">under-construction</a></li><li><a href="index70a4.html?area=houses">houses</a></li><li><a href="index9244.html?area=cabins">cabins</a></li><li><a href="indexf594.html?area=renovations">renovations</a></li><li><a href="index0890.html?area=competitions">competitions</a></li><li><a href="indexc340.html?area=lil">lil\'</a></li><li><a href="index438c.html?area=media">media</a></li><li><a href="indexb765.html?area=studio">studio</a></li><li><a href="index3213.html?area=contact">contact</a></li></ul></div>'); 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can't you just do it with css media queries?

Comment: @andrex css media queries can't insert and remove divs specifically where I want in the html document. It's all about the position of where I want the navs to be.

Comment: What I meant to say is,  can't you just use css media queries to hide/show the element in mobile and in desktop.  You don't need to physically remove it, hiding it should just be enough. Most of the responsive website's are done using css only.

Comment: @andrex Okay, so I should have another `navPrimary` div in the `colRight` hardcoded in the html and style to `display:none`? Note, I have two css stylesheets, one for desktop and one for mobile, but the html is the same. Am I on the right track or?

Comment: You are right for the most part, for the two css stylesheet you don't need to make two of them you can just use one and add **@media queries** to it.  For more information about media queries you can go here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries of you can google `css media queries`  it's easy and fun just read more about it